How to structure Python package to allow for testing
I'm having trouble being able to get my code to be executable and testable. Here's my project's file structure:
project/
├── .pytest_cache/
│
├── src/
│   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── .pytest_cache/
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
│
├── tests/
|   ├── .pytest_cache/
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── test_module.py
|
├── venv/

where both __init__.py files are empty
I'm using pytest and calling test_module.py by calling pytest in the cli at the root level of the project. This works when I use absolute imports in all of my modules in src: from src.module2.py import some_func, some_other_func 
but then executing module1.py from the cli no longer works:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project\src\module1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.module2 import some_func, some_other_func,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

However, when I remove the src. from the import statements, I can execute the scripts just fine, but no longer test them.
I've tried appending my src directory to the project path in the testfile:
test_module.py:
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../src')))

Also tried this:
test_module.py:
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.pardir))

then calling my test in the root of my project: python -m tests.test_module and nothing happens.
What can I do so executing tests & my scripts are possible? Are there any libs/packages to make this easier?

I think you have to run your tests with pytest, there's no need to append your src directory. Did you try to run pytest at the top of your directory ?

Why does src contain __init__.py? It's typically meant for packages.

If you have src in an import statement, you're definitely doing something wrong. The whole point of using a src sub-directory at all is to prevent accidentally importing from the current directory. If you've just renamed your package to "src" for the purposes of this question, don't do that - it's needlessly confusing.

Try setting the PYTHONPATH when running tests. See: Using pytest with a src layer and Ensuring py.test includes the application directory in sys.path

@farch Yep, I tried calling pytest at the top of the directory

@navneethc I was kind of just trying anything to see what would work, but also I had thought a collection of scripts/modules would be considered a package. Though I take it that's incorrect?

@wim No, I didn't rename it for the purpose of the question. I think I added src in a import statement from what I had found researching in an attempt to solve this. Didn't mean to be confusing, I'm just not sure how to be naming/organizing my code/project.

@Mr.Polywhirl Thank you! adding a pyproject.toml file at the top level of my directory + [tool.pytest.ini_options] pythonpath = [   "src" ] worked.

@gfdavb The src/ directory is conventionally taken to mean the directory where your source code resides and nothing more; it does not have any other meaning with respect to packages and modules as understood in Python. You import modules and packages, but not your source code directory.

Python Packaging User Guide src layout vs flat layout reference: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/

Before diving into testing, ensure your project is structured properly.
Project Structure
Your src/ directory should contain a subdirectory with the name of your module:
super-cool-module/
├── src/
│   └── super_cool_module/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── submodule1.py
│       └── submodule2.py
├── tests/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_submodule1.py
│   └── test_submodule2.py
├── venv/
├── setup.py    # setuptools
├── README.md   # Documentation
└── .gitignore  # Exclude venv, etc.

Alternatively, if you prefer not to use a src/ directory:
super-cool-module/
├── super_cool_module/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── submodule1.py
│   └── submodule2.py
├── tests/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test_submodule1.py
│   └── test_submodule2.py
├── venv/
├── setup.py    # setuptools
├── README.md   # Documentation
└── .gitignore  # Exclude venv, etc.

Testing Setup
To run tests, you have a few options:

Using PYTHONPATH:
Run pytest with the path to your src directory:
PYTHONPATH=src pytest


Pytest Configuration:
Alternatively, you can set up a pytest.ini configuration file:
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
pythonpath = src


Editable Mode Installation:
If you’ve activated your virtual environment, install your module in editable mode:
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -e .

Now you can run tests by simply calling:
pytest

This works because your module is installed in your local environment.


Note: Remember to exclude the venv/ directory from version control by adding it to your .gitignore file.

Tests subdir should not have an __init__.py file in it.

For people having the same issue, what I did was add a pyproject.toml file at the top level of my directory + [tool.pytest.ini_options] pythonpath = [   "src" ]

Option 3 is best here. Option 1 and 2 are hacks for when you don't have a setup.py / pyproject.toml at all, so you can't do an installation.

@wim why shouldn't they have it? I tried deleting it, but then my modules can't resolve my imports

I explain why the tests/__init__.py file should not be there in a lot of detail over here. It is quite subtle, and the presence of the file affects import statements only due to a side-effect of pytest internals (specifically the way pytest collection works). It is not something you should rely on. Beware that the top-voted/accepted answer on that Q&A is bad.
